# javascript accordion does not trigger on the very first click

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, accordion

I have made an accordion using vanilla JS. It's 99% there, but when you first click on the accordion it does not activate it.

The `data-attribute` is not set to `true` until the second click.

The `JS` code is below and there is a working example in the link.

```
  // Get the DOM element.
const accordions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js- 
accordion'));

const handleClick = accordion => () => {
// Here we set the data attribute of the selected accordion.
const selectedState = accordion.dataset.selected;
/**
 * If the selected accordion's data attribute equals true –
 * then we set it to false.
 */
accordion.dataset.selected = (accordion.dataset.selected === 'true') ? 'false' : 'true'; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign

// Set variables
const container = accordion.querySelector('.js-accordion__container');
const body = accordion.querySelector('.js-accordion__body');
const unit = 'px';

/**
 * When the state of the accordion is set to true
 * we return the height of the content and
 * and set the collapsible state to true.
 */
if (selectedState === 'true') {
  container.style.height = `${body.offsetHeight + unit}`;
  accordion.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
} else {
  container.style.height = null;
  accordion.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
 }
};

 // Bind the event listener.
 accordions.map(accordion => accordion.querySelector('.js- 
 accordion__trigger').addEventListener('click', 
 handleClick(accordion)));
```

[CodePen Example:](https://codepen.io/antonymoss/pen/dwEvZZ)

Comment: Without any code or a minimal example demonstrating the problem we'll have a hard time helping.

Comment: Yea sorry I posted before I had finished editing.

Comment: _“The data-attribute is not set to true until the second click.”_ - because your `accordion.dataset.selected` is `undefined` at first, as simply logging it to console would have shown you …

Comment: @misorude yes I realised this, but how do I solves this issue? I tried setting the initial state to `true`, but this breaks the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because your `selectedState` variable is placed before you update your accordion’s selected attribute.

You can try placing the code where you update the selected attribute for the accordion above `selectedState`